# Hyperledger Fabric- HistoryQueryIterator using nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to create hyperledger chaincode using nodejs and fabric-shim is new to me.
I am trying to fetch history of an asset using `getHistoryForKey()`.

I tried iterating through `HistoryQueryIterator` using `while` but i was not successful.

```
@Transaction()
public async getAllHistory(ctx:Context,key:string):Promise<void>{
    const history = await ctx.stub.getHistoryForKey(key);
     while(history.next()){
         history.next().then(value =>{
            console.info("================>",value.toString());
         })
         .catch(err =>{
            console.info("ERROR",err);
         })
     }

}
```

The above code gives `[object Object]`.

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an example about how to use `getHistoryForKey` in the official Hyperledger Fabric samples ( chaincodes/marbles02).

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/marbles02/node/marbles_chaincode.js